# How do I occasionally stop CodeIgniter's URL Helper's anchor() method, not to display URL suffix?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for a toy project (for learning), and I am adding URL suffix (.html) to the URL by setting `$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';` in `application/config/config.php`.
I'm getting nice url suffix at the end of all the links, e.g.,

```
www.mysite.com/main.html
www.mysite.com/profile.html
www.mysite.com/posts.html
```

But sometimes URL suffix doesn't look beautiful at the end of some URLs, e.g., `www.mysite.com/posts/delete/2.html`. In this case I want it to be `www.mysite.com/posts/delete/2`, not with the suffix (.html).

I know a workaround for that, because when I use `<a href="<?=site_url('posts/delete/'.$row->id);?>">Delete</a>` it will give me the suffix, but if I use `<a href="<?=base_url('posts/delete/'.$row->id);?>">Delete</a>` it won't give me the suffix.

But I want to get the same functionality from the CodeIgniter's anchor() method, because if I use `<?= anchor('posts/delete/' . $row->id, 'Delete'); ?>`, it will always give me the url suffix. There is again a workaround, that if I use `base_url()` inside `anchor()` it will give me the link without a suffix, but that looks so sloppy.

`<?= anchor(base_url('posts/delete/'.$row->id), 'Delete'); ?>` will translate to what I want (a url without suffix), but I don't wanna use `base_url()` inside `anchor()`. It doesn't look beautiful.

Comment: `anchor` function uses `site_url`  to generate links so you cannot get url without suffix but you can extend the helper and override the functionality. refer this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html to extend the helper.

Comment: As @Kamran said, anchor function uses `site_url`. If you want to change that, you can check `url_helper.php` file under `system/helpers/` folder but I'm not suggesting that 'cause changing core files is not a good idea.

Comment: I think I'll use html's <a></a> in that case. Anyway thanks for the comments.